# Compare IQueryable to String in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, string-comparison, iqueryable

I have this IQueryable here :

[image]

- First problem:

  The error that is shown in the picture. I cant find the cast applicable to that situation. I was wondering if anyone had an idea where to find it.
- Second problem:

  I want to be able to compare the query result to a string stored in one of my view models.

The way i would call the IQueryable would be like :

```
 var code = securityCodeCheck(item.SelectedDistrict);
```

and my comparison would be like:

```
if (item.DistrictCode == code)
{
     return view();
}

else{
     return RedirectToAction(....);
}
```

how would I go about being able to compare the 2 successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem you are selecting `District.securityCode` (which i assume is a string)

Try to select `District` as that would be the right `IQueryable` to fix the error since the method clearly defines it as a return type.

Code change would be as below.

```
var query = from District in db.Districts
 where District.leaID.Equals(district)
select District;
```

For problem 2.

You can use as below.

```
var code = securityCodeCheck(item.SelectedDistrict);

if(item.DistrictCode == code.First().securityCode)
{
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: The first problem was fixed. For the second problem, the line: `item.DistrictCode == code.securityCode` is not working. The error is: `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.linq.IQueryable<Staff_Form.Models.District>'`

Comment: Also, when i type in `code.`, `securityCode` does not come up as an option. Only options such as `toString, toArray`

Comment: @BrandonLumsden Oh .. since its an IQueryable i'm supposed to get one of the items it contains. i'll update my answer now.

Comment: works perfectly now! thank you. so the `first()` is just grabbing the first instance of security code?

Comment: @BrandonLumsden Yes it is ... since we have no idea how many of them the query returns .. and it could even throw an error if nothing is returned ..so you might want to do a check before using it .. you would say `if(code.Any())`